# How to connect two PCs with nomachine? What goes where?

Tags: remote-desktop

I I have two PC, both running Ubuntu 11.10. They are running on the same LAN, both are connected via wireless. I usually connect them with the default running Remote desktop Viewer on PC1 and Desktop Sharing on PC2. The connection is so damn slow it is unusable. People will recommend Nomachine for much faster remote desktop, but I cant understand how to configure the connection.

If, I want to view the desktop of PC2 with PC1, what do I have to install where.
It seems to me that I have to install Nomachine client on PC1, but how do I have to configure PC2 so it can be accessible with PC1. Do I have to install something?

I tried starting "desktop sharing" on PC2, but cant seem to connect with Nomachine client.

Any help welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following wiki guides should tell you what you need to know:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NomachineNX

Comment: Some SSH knowledge is needed, it seems :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what you installed on PC2. On PC1 you need the NoMachine client, and on PC2 you will need the NoMachine (server) package. e.g. NoMachine for Linux, assuming your remote PC2 is running Ubuntu. Or you can install Workstation on PC2 which gives you the terminal server functionalities and lets you run virtual Linux desktops.